# timer doesn't contain definition of "change"

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I have timer that starts counting when a certain event (`someEvent`) occurs for one second, if the event is fired again within this second I want the first timer to stop and starts counting again from 0 I tried this :

```
 void someEvent (object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e ) 
        {

            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            aTimer.Change(5000, 0);
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            aTimer.AutoReset = true;

            aTimer.Enabled = true;

        }
```

timer definition in the MainWindow:

```
private  System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
```

According to this [C# Timer.Change Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316514/c-sharp-timer-change-method)

But I get an error over aTimer.Change saying: "timer doesn't contain a definition of 'Change'."

This was implemented using WPF.

Comment: It looks like the `Change()` method is on the [`System.Threading.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) class as opposed to the `System.Timers.Timer` class.

Comment: If you are using WPF (and you want the timer to fire on the UI thread) you might want to consider switching to [`System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Two common solutions for this type of problem are a) use the class you're reading the documentation for, or b) read [the documentation for the class you're using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx). Both work well. In some cases, however, we find that we're using the wrong class, and reading the documentation for a different wrong class. That can be very confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Namespaces Matter**

.NET has quite a few timers classes, each of which have their own specific functionality and exposed methods, so it can be easy to get confused between the namespaces (as most of the classes are just called `Timer`).

You are currently using the [`System.Timers.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) class, which primarily consists of the `Start()` and `Stop()` methods. If you want the [`Change()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.change(v=vs.110).aspx) method, you would need to instead use an instance of the [`System.Threading.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) class :

```
// Declare the timer as the other type of timer
aTimer = new System.Threading.Timer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yours is a `System.Timers.Timer`. This timer does not have a `Change Method`

The `Timer.Change()` event is used in `System.Threading.Timer` [Timer.Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.change(v=vs.110).aspx)